# How can i increase the number of connections alive with Jmeter http request?

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I'm working with Jmeter to test my rest api, but it takes too much time in the Connection Time. I changed the implementation to HttpClient4 and the time is better. My question is if its possible to setup the number of connections keep alive in Jmeter?